# redirect to a different JsonResult using string parameter

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

Trying to do something dynamic here. Most calls to this action will pass a parameter of "none" for actionName, however, occasionally there will be a call that passes the name of an action I want to return data from instead of this one. The reason it's dynamic, is that it's reading values from a database, so the function that calls it may or not have the actionName override. I need to be able to redirect to another JsonResult using the actionName parameter as the name of the JsonResult to redirect to. Is there a way to call another JsonResult by name and then pass the results back in this function?

```
public JsonResult GetBadgeValues(int badgeId, string actionName) {
    if (actionName != "none") {
        return actionName;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a verbose answer, but it should work:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<JsonResult>> nameToMethodDict = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<string, JsonResult>>(){
        {"name", otherMethod}
    };

public JsonResult GetBadgeValues(int badgeId, string actionName) {
    if (actionName != "none") {
        return actionName;
    }  
    else {
        return nameToMethodDict[actionName]();
    }
}

public JsonResult otherMethod() {
    ...
}
```

I would reconsider this architecture, though, because if you want to return different data depending on some value in the database it really should be set-based logic in a stored procedure as opposed to this silly string->delegate relationship. If, on the other hand, you have only 5 or some countable number of possible actionName values, then you should really make them individual MVC routes.